# Specify destination directory for Laravel Spatie backup

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using [Laravel Spatie Backup](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-backup) to backup my Laravel project. Right now the backup gets stored in the `myproject/storage/app` directory. How can I change this directory to for example `myproject/storage/app/some/directory`? 
I can't find a clear answer on this.

My `laravel-backup.php` config right now:

```
'destination' => [

    /*
     * The disk names on which the backups will be stored.
     */
    'disks' => [
        'local'
    ],
],
```

I tried the following: `'local' => '/some/directory'` but this throws the error  `Copying .zip file failed because: Could not connect to disk /some/directory because the disk is not set..`

Comment: If you make sure the path exists, you can set the destination filename_prefix to include the path

Comment: Or you can create a new config in config/file with the correct postfix and use that...

Answer (score 2):

first go to `config/filesystems.php`

add new disk to your project

```
  'disks' => [

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
        ],


        // add your own disk to the project
        'localBackup' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/your_directory') // your folder,
        ],

        ....
  ]
```

in the config/backup.php

```
 'destination' => [

            /*
             * The filename prefix used for the backup zip file.
             */
            'filename_prefix' => 'backup_',

            /*
             * The disk names on which the backups will be stored.
             */
            'disks' => [
                'localBackup',//your disk
            ],
        ],
```